# Why is "страхам" in the dative in "Страхам дней минувших меня уж не догнать"?

Tags: склонение

The song lyric "Страхам дней минувших меня уж не догнать" translates to something like "The fears of days past don't reach me anymore". I understand why "дней минувших" is in the genitive, because they "own" the fears, I understand why "меня" is in the accusative, because it's the object that's (not) being "reached", but I have no idea why the "стра́хи" aren't in the nominative. After all, they're the ones performing the verb (догнать). Why are they instead in the dative case?

Comment: A simple way taught to understand the case is to ask a question to the statement. _**Кому** меня уж не догнать?_ - _**Страхам**_. It could be nominative - _Страхи дней минувших меня уже не смогут догнать_. _**Кто** не сможет догнать?_ - _**Страхи**_.

Comment: @Vilmar My Russian isn't really strong enough to understand what you're saying. Are you implying there's a significant difference between Кому and кто? I also don't really see how the linked duplicate question answers this one.

Comment: @JackM In nominative case there would be: _страхи_ меня не _догонят_. But here you have infinitive-based construction which must use dative case: _страхам_ меня не _догнать_. The meaning is almost the same, but the syntax is quite different. And the duplicate question is really dedicated to such constructions. Try to read it carefully.

Comment: @Vilmar: I believe the op was able to understand the case (it's in the title after all), it's just they don't understand why was this particular case used.